# NLP and multi-level text classification

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I define text commands for controlling home smart devices. Each commands (there are about 6 different commands ) are labeled. I need also and additional label: "out-of-scope". It could be anything else which do not fit into those 6 categories/labels.
How I can get such "out-of-scope" dataset?  If datasets are mutually exclusive, that dataset could be big.
Thanks in advance